# Multiple stdout to one stdin

Tags: stdout, stdin

I'm on Windows, although I could be on Linux so solutions for either are welcome.

I have a program that is essentially a game with 4 players that take an instruction from each of those players. Basically the idea is to have 4 groups to create an AI for this game. I need to route the stdout of all 4 of these AI programs to the stdin of my contest program. How would I do that?

Comment: `mkfifo`, [CreatePipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ?

Comment: Does one pipe work for multiple stdout?

Comment: See example in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Named pipes accepts output from anybody (if permissions allow it)

```
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo -m 666 /tmp/myfifo.pipe

( echo 'Proc1' 1> /tmp/myfifo.pipe ) &
PID1=$!
( echo 'Proc2' 1> /tmp/myfifo.pipe ) &
PID2=$!
( echo 'Proc3' 1> /tmp/myfifo.pipe ) &
PID3=$!

 cat </tmp/myfifo.pipe > result.txt

wait $PID1 $PID2 $PID3

rm -f /tmp/myfifo.pipe
```